# Is there a way to edit the notification bar?

Tags: mount, notification

So I use Ubuntu 22.04, and I wonder if there is a way to customize notification:

[image]

So there is callendar and media player info in there, but is there a way to mount something here?

[image]

Like, to mount something to play this video. So if I open the notification, I can open my media. This is just a question out of curiosity

Comment: You can, but you will likely need to program. With Gnome Shell Extensions, such things could be done.